# Only Integers (List Validation Settings) with condition

Tags: list, column, validation, number

I just discovered the Validation Settings and think they are so helpful!

I implemented column validations that check if the number is an integer but now that gives me an error with my workflow (because the workflow is calculating a mean value and I don't want to round that result!)

What I try to achieve:

- I have a column 'Item type' and there are the types 'Record' and 'Conclusion'
- when people fill in the Records they shouldn't be allowed to fill in decimals
- when Item type=conclusion it should be allowed

Is this possible with list validation settings?

Thanks in advance!